# Get the max date from a list of value inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, max

I don´t find a elegant Linq way to retrieve the Max date assigned to a person in a list of person that are alocated to a mission.

My code is

```
public class Mission
{
    public string MissonAssignedTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Mission>>> MissionList = 
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Mission>>>();
```

I Have this dictionary with this kind of values

```
MissionList[0] Key = MissionImpossible
            Value = count 1
                  Key=Sean
                  Value=count 7
                        [0] = date = 10/01/2017
                        [1] = date = 10/01/2016
                        [2] = date = 10/01/2017
                        [3] = date = 10/01/2018
                        [4] = date = 10/01/2015
                        [5] = date = 10/01/2014
                        [6] = date = 10/01/2013

MissionList[1] Key = MissionImpossibleThePayPack
            Value = count 1
                  Key=Connery
                  Value=count 4
                        [0] = date = 10/01/2017
                        [1] = date = 10/01/2019
                        [2] = date = 10/01/2017
                        [3] = date = 10/01/2018
```

I need to retrieve a dictionary for each Person and his max date, something like this.

```
dicoResult= { 
                {Sean,10/01/2018} , 
                {Connery,10/01/2019} 
            }
```

Best regards.
Jolynice

Comment: Can you provide valid c# code for dictionaries sample? And show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your custom type looks weird to me, If I have understood you correctly then this should give you the expected result:-

```
var result = MissionList.SelectMany(x => x.Value)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.Max(z => z.Date));
```

First flatten your inner dictionary and finally project the result to a dictionary using `ToDictionary`.

[Sample Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V7WdJb)

Comment: Thank you Rahul, Your are rigth my custom type is weird, I think I will change it to something more precise.